# How to set gasPrice using hardhat in EVM smart contract

Tags: evm, astar

- I was developing a contract on EVM on Shibuya, Astar Network's testnet.
- I'm using hardhat.
- We successfully deployed to Shibuya testnet and Shiden network using the following settings.
- But it doesn't work well with Astar Network.

```
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";

const { privateKey } = require('./private.json');

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url:"http://localhost:8545",
      chainId:31337,
      accounts: [privateKey]
    },
    shibuya: {
      url:"https://shibuya.public.blastapi.io",
      chainId:81,
      accounts: [privateKey]
    },
    shiden: {
      url:"https://shiden.public.blastapi.io",
      chainId:336,
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
    astar: {
      url:"https://astar-rpc.dwellir.com",
      chainId:592,
      accounts: [privateKey]
    }
  },
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I asked a core team engineer how to work around this issue.
- There's a way to use the API to get gas, and a way to let hardhat do it.

API: https://docs.astar.network/docs/integrations/api/gas_api/#api

sample settings:

```
import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";

const { privateKey } = require('./private.json');

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.9",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url:"http://localhost:8545",
      chainId:31337,
      accounts: [privateKey],
      gasPrice: "auto"
    },
    shibuya: {
      url:"https://shibuya.public.blastapi.io",
      chainId:81,
      accounts: [privateKey],
      gasPrice: "auto"
    },
    shiden: {
      url:"https://shiden.public.blastapi.io",
      chainId:336,
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
    astar: {
      url:"https://astar-rpc.dwellir.com",
      chainId:592,
      accounts: [privateKey],
      gasPrice: 4000000000
    }
  },
};

export default config;
```